# Possessing two residence IDs of different schengen countries

Tags: schengen, netherlands, eu, belgium, residency

I am a Non EU citizen, residing in Belgium as a dependent to my spouse. Recently I got admitted to a Masters course in Netherlands for fall 2016. The university will be applying for my student visa/ Student residence ID to Netherlands. As I will be living 4 nights in Netherlands and the weekend 3 nights in Belgium is it ok or legal to possess two residence IDs? One as a dependent in Belgium and one as a student in Netherlands?

Comment: I guess you mean non-EU **citizen** at the start there?

Comment: yes, did the correction

Comment: In general those things that are not prohibited are legal.  It is going to be difficult to prove the absence of a prohibition against having two residence cards.

Comment: I noticed ths question is put on hold and I am advised to use Expatriates Stack Exchange instead. Apologies for posting it in the wrong site. I have posted a question there. Thank you everyone for your help.